# How to determine the uniqueness of an internal transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, internal-transactions

How to determine the uniqueness of an internal transaction

Example is this transaction: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xc756517a69239bddffe3e0cb07eba98d3ad0fae1b44fc936a0119dbaf7008942#internal

they are exact identical of each other **(including tx-hash, type, traceId)**, and I need a way to differentiate those transactions to know if I've already processed the transaction or not.

I'm using etherscan.io to detect internal transactions by iterating block by block. If I were to rebuild the database, I need a way to know if X transaction has already been recorded/processed/seen before or not.